# job succeeded, app-deploy Passed and yet trailhead playground doesn't show deployed change

Tags: gitlab, salesforce

(job succeeded, app-deploy Passed and yet trailhead playground doesn't show deployed change - could not find the unlocked package 'DreamHouse' installed)

[image]I'm at Step 2 of Review Your Deployment section of module "Deploy to Production with CI/CD" of "Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab" trailhead and NOT seeing "Property Finder" tab in my Trailhead Playground like I should.  Saw it earlier with Scratch org per previous step(s).  This most likely resulted in "We could not find the unlocked package 'DreamHouse' installed upon clicking "Verify step to earn 100 points".

I would like to resolve this issue.  Anyone with suggestion(s)?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Tien